# Java Uploaded File Name Turkish Character Issue in JSF - Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I use Primefaces `p:fileUpload` dialog. When I use some specific Turkish characters in file name like "ğ ü ş ı ö ç" I can't get them corretly and can't save the uploaded file on disc.

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){
    String newName = new String(event.getFile().getFileName("ISO-8859-1").getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

or I also tried this one:

```
String newName = new String(event.getFile().getFileName("ISO-8859-1").getBytes(), "ISO-8859-9");
```

How to get or convert the letters corretly? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the following filter in your web.xml, before the file upload filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.examples.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

now simple `event.getFile().getFileName()` should print the proper name